# how i can place 50% control over the tool bar in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

how i can place 50% of control just like 50 % image view over the menu bar and rest 50% of control over the page just as in screenshot ?[image: please find attached screenshot...as showing in image there is circular image ,half section of image placed over the toolbar and rest placed over the page]

I tried to achieve this using relative layout but could not able to do that..
please anyone know help me to design such UI.

```
        <Button  HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" BorderRadius="35" BackgroundColor="Aqua"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor = .5}"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor = -.05}" />
```

Comment: Most basic method would be to set the `TranslationY` property to a negative value.

Comment: ok..Gerald i will try this ..

Comment: I try this but the menu bar overlap the button         <Button  HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" BorderRadius="35" BackgroundColor="Aqua"
    RelativeLayout.XConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor = .5}"
             RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor = -.05}" />

Comment: Add your code in question its hard to read in comment.

Comment: Question has been edited ....u can check now Ziyad

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using absolute layout

```
          <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="white">
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Aqua" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0
                    0,1,100" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional,YProportional,WidthProportional" />
                <Button BackgroundColor="White"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,75,70,70" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional" BorderRadius="35" />
                <Button BackgroundColor="Red" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5
                    80,60,60" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional" BorderRadius="30" />
            </AbsoluteLayout>
```

[Reference](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout/)

Comment: With absolute layout also toolbar overlaps the button.

Comment: @nitu Put your button in ContentView